# Using a UIColor category in iOS 7 and Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, objective-c-category

I have a UIColor+MyLayout.m file such as:

```
@implementation UIColor (Layout)

- (UIColor *) textBackground
{
    UIColor *lightGreen = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:178.0f/255.0f     blue:238.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    return lightGreen;
}

@end
```

I have added the .h file to my viewcontroller.m, but how do I call this into a UIColor?

UIColor *myColor = ?

Comment: You want `+ (UIColor *) textBackground` not `- (UIColor *) textBackground`.  Then you can simply use it as in the answer provided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would be better if you do the following:

```
@implementation UIColor (Layout)

+ (UIColor *) textBackground {
    UIColor *lightGreen = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:178.0f/255.0f        blue:238.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    return lightGreen;
}

@end
```

And then just call it `UIColor *myColor = [UIColor textBackground];`

Comment: He also needs to import the category.

Answer (score 4):

[Huge screenshot showing coloured text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKwaS.png)

**TRY THIS.... IT IS WORKING!!!!**

**1.** MAke the subclass of `UIColor` named vv.

So, in **UIColor+vv.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (vv)
+(UIColor*)mh;
@end
```

**UIColor+vv.m**

```
#import "UIColor+vv.h"

@implementation UIColor (vv)
+(UIColor*)mh
{
     UIColor *lightGreen = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:178.0f/255.0f     blue:238.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    return lightGreen;
}
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "UIColor+vv.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    lbl.textColor=[UIColor mh];
}
```

**LET me know if you have any problem.**

Comment: You have to make the subclass of `UIColor` instead of `LAyoput`.

Comment: IS this helpful to you? If you try this & get any problem, let me know. It is working for me.

Comment: Why repeat existing answers? And why the HUGE screenshot?

Comment: @MartinR, I am not repeating the same answer. Just see all other answers. They are making the Subclass of `Layout` instead of `UIColor`. & the others answer are not accepted so I try to show the output with the following code.

Answer (score 3):

You should make this method static like...

```
@implementation UIColor (Layout)

+ (UIColor *) textBackground {
    UIColor *lightGreen = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:178.0f/255.0f        blue:238.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    return lightGreen;
}

@end
```

And then just call it using class name like

`UIColor *myColor = [UIColor textBackground];`

You should import UIColor+MyLayout.h like

`#import UIColor+MyLayout.h`

Comment: That's a *class* method, not a *static* method. In fact the same answer has been given above.

Comment: Static method is infact a class method

Answer (score 1):

You can turn `textBackground` into class method by using `+` in signature instead of `-` and then simply:

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor textBackground];
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to import your category file in your class like:

```
#import "UIColor+Layout.h"
```

Then you need to call this method as

```
[UIColor textBackground]
```

Also you need to make your category method as a class method