# IOS/Objective-C: Convert standard UIColor to CGColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcolor

I have set a color in an NSUserDefault in another class and and now want to convert it to a CGColor for display.  I can convert an actual UIColor to a CGColor.  But I'm having trouble converting a UIColor stored in a variable to a CGColor

```
UIColor* myColor = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:myColor];
struct CGColor* circleColor = nil;
circleColor=[[UIColor greenColor]CGColor];//this works 
circleColor=[[myColor] CGColor];//does not work
circleColor=[myColor CGColor];//does not work
```

Can anyone suggest the right way to do this?

Note: I did not save a cgcolor in the userdefaults due to the need to bridge

Comment: Have you tried `circleColor=[myColor CGColor];`? There shouldn't be square brackets around `myColor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't save UIColor object in NSUserDefaults directly.

try to archive object to get data and save the data like this:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorData forKey:@"ColorKey"];
```

And when you need the color firstly you should get NSData object from User Defaults and then create UIColor object like this

```
NSData *colorData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ColorKey"];
UIColor *color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
```

Comment: out of curiosity, I guess there is no way to save a string in the NSuserdefault as in @"greenColor" and use that to generate [UIColor greenColor]?

Comment: yes you can generate a new object. It depends on what are you doing. if you want to save a color generated by user and load it after some times. than user defaults is great to do such work.

Comment: what would correct syntax be for NSString *colorstr = @"greencolor";  UIColor* myColor =[UIColor colorstr];  latter does not work.(stars don't show in comment)

Comment: when you type [UIColor greenColor] it means that you are calling UIColor class method "greenColor". it is impossible to type here variable declared earlier. like this [UIColor colorstr]; you will get compile error.

Comment: So there is no way to simply generate standard color from string

Comment: from string no, but you can create UIColor category and add your own custom methods to UIColor class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397024/using-a-uicolor-category-in-ios-7-and-objective-c

Comment: Ok.  Got it .  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
circleColor = [[myColor] CGColor];//does not work
```

with

```
circleColor = myColor.CGColor;
```

**EDIT**

If you haven't saved your `UIColor` in `NSUSerDefaults` check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1275790/3789527) for an example on how to correctly store and retrieve it.

Comment: You were right about syntax.  However, I had second error in saving in NSUser Defaults.  I upvoted you but marked other one correct as it was deeper issue.

Comment: It's Objective-C, that square bracket syntax is perfectly valid for properties

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't create `myColor` object in this line.

```
UIColor* myColor = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:myColor];
struct CGColor* circleColor = nil;
```

First initialise that object then assign on that object with your `user defaults` then proceed accordingly.